# Is it possible to find an instance of an object without it being passed to the method?

Tags: java, class-design, classloader

I have a parser class "MessageParser" which i pass a message which is of type "String" to it for it to be parsed. The parsing method signature for the class is

```
public void parse(String message);
```

I need to pass an instance of "Properties" to it but i dont want to change the signature of the method to add a new argument to it. I have been struggling with this for the last couple of days and have tried a couple of options - see [Sending in an object of type Object instead of String - Polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134462/sending-in-an-object-of-type-object-instead-of-string-polymorphism)

The class that calls the parsing method "ParserManager" knows of the properties object. Is there a way for the MessageParser to find the properties object without it being passed to it?

### Edit

Here is some example code. 
I would like the "MessageCparser" to access the "prop" object in "ParserManager" without changing anything in the "Parser" interface or the "ParserManager" class. Is this possible?

```
public interface Parser{
    public void parse(String message);
}

public class MessageCParser implements Parser{
    public void parse(String message){
        MessageObject mobject = (MessageObject)message; 
        System.out.println("Parsing C" + mobject.getMessage());
    }

    public void parse(String m){}
}


import java.util.HashMap;

public class ParserManager{

Properties prop = null;

    public ParserManager() {
        prepare();
    prop = new Properties()
    }

    HashMap parsers = new HashMap();


    public void prepare(){

        parsers.put("A",new MessageCParser());

    }

    public void parseMessage(String msgType, String message){
        ((Parser)parsers.get(msgType)).parse(message);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most evident solution would be to add a reference to the `Properties` object as a field in the `ParserManager`, and then either provide the `ParserManager` with the properties object as a constructor argument or through a setter-method as shown below:

```
class ParserManager {
    ...
    Properties props;

    public void setParsingProperties(Properties props) {
        this.props = props;
    }

    public void parse(String message) {
        // props available here, without being passed as agurment.
    }
}

class CallingParserManager {
    ...
    void someMethod() {
        ...
        parserManager.setParsingProperties(propertiesToUse);
        parserManager.parse(theString);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Looking at your previous question, I'd say it would be fine if you added a `setParsingProperties` in the `Parser` interface. The method can be implemented as an empty method for those parser that don't need the properties.

---

**Regarding your edit:** No, it's not possible to solve it like that.

```
MessageObject mobject = (MessageObject) message;
```

Will only work if `MessageObject` is a subtype of `String` (but since `String` is final (can't be extended) that cannot be the case).

The dirty quick-fix would be to check (with `instanceof`) if the `Parser` is an instance of `MessageCParser` and cast it and then use a `MessageCParser` specific parse method that takes the `Properties` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are four ways of getting information, broadly speaking:

- It could be part of the state of the object that the method is called on (e.g. it could be passed to the constructor and then retained in a field)
- It can be a parameter of the method itself
- It could be accessed statically, e.g. via a singleton
- It could be accessed via a thread-local variable

All of these can be used with indirection of course - for example, if something *else* which knows about the `Properties` is available via one of the above mechanisms, then you can get to that and then find out about the `Properties`. But you can't just find out the calling object and ask *that*.

What do you need to do with the `Properties` in question? Would the `Properties` vary on a call-by-call basis for the same `MessageParser`? If so, it really *should* be a parameter. You say you don't want to change the signature of the method - but if you want to pass more information in, that's exactly what you *should* do.

Comment: @Stephen C: Ick, yes. I guess that's a variation on statics. I'll add it to the list.

Comment: at the implementation level, thread-locals are really "none of the above".  They are implemented as a per-thread hash table, and rely (critically) on the "magic" that allows you to find out what the current thread is.  (Agreed - Ick - but they have their uses.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one instance of your "Properties" object, you can use something like the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

You can also add a reference to the ParserManager somewhere in your MessageParser and then call a method on ParserManager which will return the Properties, but without some code snippets it's impossible to help you further than this.